# Why my StringBuilder.AppendLine method won't save non-english letters in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I am working on a school project and the task was to create an application, which one of the features is to save multi-lined text (user input) into a string. I know some parts of the code might be outdated, but our school compiler **only supports .NET version 4** (edit: I compile in Visual Studio 2022, school compiler is only the place where we showcase the final work, that is why the version is a limit for finished work). I am still learning and I am sure there are other things that could be improved, but let's look at the main problem.

When the user types standard Czech text (for example "včera", which means yesterday), the text saved and later returned shows "vera". If I type only these special characters, for example "ůčšěž", which doesn't mean anything, the string content is left empty.
When I create a string using different method, for example basic `Console.WriteLine()`, the special characters are saved just okay.
The method I am using is supposed to take user input and supply that multi-lined text together with DateTime to an object Record inside a doubly linked list. Below, I will show the relevant code because the mistake could be created on the way.

```
public static void CreateNewRecord()
{
    Console.Write("Date: ");
    if (DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out DateTime parsedDate))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nText: ");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (true)
        {
            string textLine = Console.ReadLine();
            if (textLine.ToLower() == "save")
                break;
            sb.AppendLine(textLine);
        }
        string recordText = sb.ToString();
        Program.records.AddLast(new Record(parsedDate, recordText));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong date format.");
    }
}
```

This creates the Record and and using the overriden ToString(), I am trying to read it:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Date: {0}\n\n{1}", Date, Text);
}
```

However, when trying to read the content using `Console.WriteLine(records.Last());`, only english-lettered text is returned.
If anyone has idea what is wrong, your answer will be welcomed.

I tried to add UTF-8 encoding to the top of my program, which didn't help. I tried to create a very simple string builder that appends parts of text (not whole lines), and it returned even with the special characters.

I expect a multi-lined text to be returned with all the symbols the user saves to it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Unicode, English or special characters. .NET strings are Unicode, always. This question proves it - StackOverflow is a .NET application. That's why I can type `Αυτό Εδώ` along with  `ůčšěž` and know everything will show up properly

Comment: Make sure the Console is able to display those chars.

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos said, all strings in .NET are Unicode. It's more likely the environment that's displaying (attempting) the text doesn't support these Unicode characters.

Comment: I made sure, as I mentioned, using different means to create those strings work perfectly. Only this part of the code won't save special characters.
@phuzi Also I compile in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Windows itself uses Unicode natively, since the very first Windows NT version back in 1994. The *Console* terminal though before Windows 10 needed tweaking to *display* Unicode text. Before Windows 10 it was assumed that only legacy non-Unicode applications would use the console. If you use a previous version you may have to change the console's codepage from its settings, or use `chcp 65000`

Comment: I use Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2022. Everything is on the latest version. By school compiler I mean the website compiler where we give our finished works. However I am not using that school compiler while creating the code, it's just a note that I cannot use some stuff added in later versions. Thanks everyone

Comment: Where are the records being stored? Perhaps the issue is there.

Comment: The `Record` class is unknown to us, and how it stores `recordText` might affect the result. You can use debugger to see recordText and then the `Record` generated in `Program.records`, see if the text is changed. This will help identifying the issue.

Comment: Records are being stored in doubly linked list, LinkedList<Record>();

Comment: You still haven't demonstrated a problem. .NET and Unicode isn't a matter of debate. Your own question proves that Unicode works. Post actual *executable* code that demonstrates any problem. Where do `Date` and `Text` come from? What are their values? If I create a console app that only reads a line and writes it back I *won't* lose any text. If I use `DateTime.TryParse()` with the wrong input though, I'll end up with an invalid date. If your *loop* has a problem, you'll end up with an empty StringBuilder

Comment: You can try to add Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; into your main

Comment: And also put `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;` (Or `UTF8`, but I usually use `Unicode` for Console I/O)

Comment: I looked at the debugger and special characters are saved to the line as "\0\0\0\0" (one slash-zero for each of the character). 
Here is the full code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K9wacJDk1z44eoUXManRj53G11dKbZ5z
Only "novy" which means "new" works at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

To help you handle special characters properly:

1. Set Console Encoding: Before reading user input and writing to the console, you should set the console's encoding to UTF-8 to handle special characters correctly. You can do this at the beginning of your program:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

2. Update Your CreateNewRecord Method: Ensure that you read user input and store it correctly with UTF-8 encoding. You can modify your CreateNewRecord method like this:

```
   public static void CreateNewRecord()
   {
       Console.Write("Date: ");
       if (DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out DateTime parsedDate))
       {
           Console.WriteLine("\nText: ");

           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

           while (true)
           {
               string textLine = Console.ReadLine();
               if (textLine.ToLower() == "save")
                   break;
               sb.AppendLine(textLine);
           }
           string recordText = sb.ToString();
           Program.records.AddLast(new Record(parsedDate, recordText));
       }
       else
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Wrong date format.");
       }
   }
```

3. Ensure Your Record Class Handles Special Characters: Make sure that your Record class properly handles special characters when storing and retrieving text. If your Record class uses a string to store the text, it should work correctly with UTF-8 encoded strings by default.

With these changes, your program should handle multi-lined text with special characters correctly. Ensure that the console encoding is set to UTF-8, and special characters should be preserved when saving and displaying the text.

Comment: You posted identical code to mine. I also mentioned I did use Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; and Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
This looks like GPT answer to me with no real information to this exact case. I appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing might be related to the encoding used when reading and writing the text. To ensure proper handling of special characters, you can try using the `Console.OutputEncoding` property to set the encoding to UTF-8 before writing the text. Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```cs
public static void CreateNewRecord()
{
    Console.Write("Date: ");
    if (DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out DateTime parsedDate))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nText: ");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (true)
        {
            string textLine = Console.ReadLine();
            if (textLine.ToLower() == "save")
                break;
            sb.AppendLine(textLine);
        }
        string recordText = sb.ToString();

        // Set the console output encoding to UTF-8
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        Program.records.AddLast(new Record(parsedDate, recordText));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong date format.");
    }
}
```

By setting the `Console.OutputEncoding` to `Encoding.UTF8`, you ensure that the console can handle and display the special characters properly.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This looked like a solution before I tried yesterday (and again today using your code), and it sadly did not solve the issue.